# Why was the value changed in Apache solr?

Tags: solr

I have some fields of tfloat-type in solr.

But sometime its value is changed by solr probably.

In my case, I gave a value "812095000" Solr, however when I checked it in Solr-Admin, it showed the value was "812094980".  I don't get it. Why changed?

And, can I get original values? I mean "812095000".

It looks that only if I give large number, this occurs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how floats work. [Floats are not exact, and can't store all exact values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate). If you need to store a large integer, use `long` instead.

Regular 32-bit floats can't store the value `812095000` as you've discovered. Instead, use a type that suits the data you're inputting (if it's integers, use an integer or a long format, or use a double field if you need floating point numbers

Comment: Now I get it.  Actually need to index point numbers, so I decided to use double field. Thanks for your advice.